# Wordpress output data to another website and pull data

Tags: plugins, rest-api, api, json

Would you like to ask, is it possible to send data from the **WordPress** website to another website, and get the data back from another website?

I would like to make a function with text insert and a button, after a click on the button the text will be sent to another website, and that website will receive data and send another data back to the **WordPress** website and Wordpress website will display the message that website sent.

Comment: using `RSS feed` you can get post from another WordPress

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible,
To achieve this you need to understand basic *REST-API* and *Server-Client* communication.

You need an API from your *Other Website* where the API will consume the input. And then your WordPress site will call that API with the parameters that contains data from your input form.

Comment: thanks for your answer , appreciate that